# React Router v6 routing with paths like https://adomain.com/blogs/sampleblog

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've defined nested routes using `createBrowserRouter` and I expected that the router would route to my child page.  However, it seems to stop at the top-level part of the url. `BlogsPage` and `SampleBlog` are both React components.

I expected `"https://adomain/blogs/sampleblog"` to get routed to `SampleBlog` not to `BlogsPage`.  I thought I could nest as deeply as I liked and that the router would match the longest matching path and invoke that component.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      { path: "", element: <HomePage /> },
      { path: "home", element: <HomePage /> },
      {
        path: "blogs",
        element: <BlogsPage /> },
        children: [
          { path: "sampleblog", element: <SampleBlog /> },
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`children` are used to render child-routes. You would need to use an `<Outlet />` inside `BlogsPage`

What you wanted to do is creating two routes at the same level

```
[
  { path: "blogs", element: <BlogsPage /> },
  { path: "blogs/sampleblog", element: <SampleBlog /> }
]
```

Comment: If I have to define a child at the same nested level as parent, when do you use a nested route?  Intuitively it seemed that what I did was what I would have expected to do.

Comment: It's not a child. You use a child when you want to render the parent as well.

Comment: To clarify this, a child is used when the parent is a "container" (rendered as well) and the parent has an <Outlet /> component in its output where the child is to be rendered.